# selecting unique random number to each row and column in table using php

Tags: unique

If I select range the number 1 to 2 , the output will come in matrix format 2X2 as,
   1st row =>1and2
   2nd row =>2and1
    (OR)
   1st row =>2and1
   2nd row =>1and2

If I select range the number 1 to 3 , the output will come in matrix format 3X3  as,
   1  2  3,
   2  3  1,
   3  1  2
    (OR)
   2  1  3,
   3  2  1,
   1  3  2
     whatever the output may come, But each cell value shouldn't come again in the same row and column.

If I select range the number 1 to 4 , the output will come in matrix 4X4 format as,

4  2  1  3,
   1  4  3  2,
   2  3  2  4,
   3  1  4  1

I need to shuffle the range.  I wish to clear this concept using php.  Pls. anyone help.....

Answer (score 1):

Since one answer is always known; `[a, b, c] => [ [ a, b, c], [ b, c, a ], [ c, a, b ] ]`, basically a repeating array_shift.

```
$startValue = 1;
$endValue = 3;

$arr = [];
for($idx = $startValue; $idx < $endValue + 1; ++$idx) 
    array_push($arr, $idx);

$result = [ $arr ];
$row = $arr;
while(count($result) < count($arr)) {
    array_push($row, array_shift($row));
    array_push($result, $row);
}

print_r($result);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 2
        )

)
```